# Why are "questions without a clear problem statement" rather off-topic than "unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

In the "off-topic" section of close reasons, there is this one options:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

It however seems to combine two reasons in one.  As far as I can interpret this, we've got:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

and also

> Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Isn't the second one the same as "not clear what is being asked" reason?

Comment: To my mind it's more of a justification for the first sentence

Comment: The whole thing is a subset of "unclear", it's just a more specific error message that is able to give more targeted advice to the author on how to improve their question.